# What happens when an abstract class implements an interface in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract

I am new to Java, coming from a C++ background and I try to understand the concept of interface and abstract class implementing an interface. What exactly happens when an abstract class implements an interface? Does this work like inheritance, i.e. all interface methods belong also to the abtract class eventhough they are not implemented in it? Or will only the implemented methods belong to the abstract class? So is there any difference between implements and extends, except that one is used to implement interfaces and the other one is used for inheritance?

Comment: What do you mean "belong to"? A concrete class extending the abstract class has to implement all the unimplemented methods in the hierarchy, wherever they may come from. I am not sure what your question actually is at this point. Could you show some code snippets that you compiled and ran showing what is actually confusing you?

Comment: Another big difference is that you can implement multiple interfaces but only extend a single class. In both cases a class has to implement the methods as soon as it isn't abstract.

Comment: Your question boils down to this: Should abstract class A be of type I which is the interface. As an example: If **any** implementation of some abstract class should be closeable, it should implement `java.io.Closeable`. Otherwise it should not.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can imagine an `abstract` class as an **unfinished** class. It's like a template for actual real classes. `Interface`s are mainly used to describe properties, like `CanWalk`, `IsCloseable`, `HasAName` and so on.

There is no big difference between both concepts from the language perspective, other than that you can only extend from one class but are allowed to implement multiple interfaces.

**In the end** of the inheritance chain you will always have **non-abstract** concrete classes. Which is obvious, you can't use unfinished classes in the end, you need to finish them. That's why

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
```

does not work if `Animal` is `abstract`. We need to create instances of finished classes, like a `Dog` who extends from `Animal`.

---

And at that point, where you have a *finished* (non-abstract) class, **all abstract methods** need to be implemented. It doesn't matter from where those methods come from, abstract classes or interfaces, they need to be implemented.

So if you have an abstract class and implement an interface with it, you have two options for the interface methods. You either

- implement them **in the abstract class** or
- you **leave them abstract**, but then some of your more concrete **children need to implement** it.

---

### Example

Let's suppose we have an interface like

```
public interface CanMakeNoise {
    void makeNoise();
}
```

and the abstract class

```
public abstract class Animal implements CanMakeNoise {
    public abstract void jump();

    ...
}
```

together with a concrete extending class

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    ...
}
```

Since `Dog` is not abstract, all methods need to be implemented. That is, we need implementations for `jump` and `makeNoise`. For the `makeNoise` method we have two options, either `Animal` implements it or it leaves it abstract, then `Dog` needs to implement it:

```
// Variant 1
public abstract class Animal implements CanMakeNoise {
    public abstract void jump();

    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("hello, what's up");
    }
}
```

or

```
// Variant 2
public abstract class Animal implements CanMakeNoise {
    public abstract void jump();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Wuff wuff");
    }
}
```

And of course `Dog` needs to implement `jump`:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override
    public void jump() {
        System.out.println("Boing");
    }

    ...
}
```

In this case it's probably better to leave the implementation of `makeNoise` up to more concrete classes since `Animal` has no clue how a specific animal will sound like.

Extending the example, if you have even more concrete classes like a `Chihuahua extends Dog`, you could implement the `makeNoise` in `Dog` since all dogs do `"Wuff, wuff"`.

Comment: Hi. Do you know by chance if this same rule applies for C#?

Comment: @Azazel I am not a C# developer but the languages are very similar. And basic OOP principles such as `abstract` and `interface` behave pretty much the same in any OOP language anyways. That said, which particular rule are you talking about - the answer covers a lot of aspects.

Answer (score 1):

A method belongs to implementing class of course. I won't say that it doesn't matter where it comes from because of polymorphism. In Java you don't have multi-inheritance but you can implement multiple interfaces, so this is giving you more options about the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, a class can only inherit from one class, but can implements multiple interfaces.

An abstract class is very similar to an interface. The main difference is that an abstract class can define some function already, an interface can’t (note that this changed in Java9+).

Which one to use? Well it really depends on your structure but the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) defines some exemple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the usage of the interface then it will be used for callbacks as Java don't support function pointers.